# Error compiling PositionalSound.cpp in dev branch

Tags: minko

As suggested to me in another question on minko, I'm trying to use the dev branch.
I get an error while compiling "minko/audio/PositionalSound.cpp".
The command was `make config=linux64_debug` and the output is

```
...
PositionalSound.cpp
+ g++ -MMD -MP -DDEBUG -DJSON_IS_AMALGAMATION -Iinclude -Ilib/sparsehash/src -Isrc -Ilib/jsoncpp/src -Ilib/glm -Ilib/sparsehash/include -g -m64 -std=c++11 -o obj/linux64/debug/PositionalSound.o -MF obj/linux64/debug/PositionalSound.d -c src/minko/audio/PositionalSound.cpp
In file included from include/minko/render/Effect.hpp:25:0,
                 from include/minko/render/DrawCallPool.hpp:25,
                 from include/minko/component/Renderer.hpp:25,
                 from include/minko/component/Transform.hpp:26,
                 from src/minko/audio/PositionalSound.cpp:25:
include/minko/render/Pass.hpp: In lambda function:
include/minko/render/Pass.hpp:200:62: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
                 setUniformOnProgram<T...>(program, name, values...);
                                                          ^
include/minko/render/Pass.hpp:200:62: note:         ‘values’
include/minko/render/Pass.hpp:200:68: error: expansion pattern ‘values’ contains no argument packs
                 setUniformOnProgram<T...>(program, name, values...);
                                                                ^
make[1]: *** [obj/linux64/debug/PositionalSound.o] Errore 1
make: *** [minko-framework] Errore 2
```

I'm on "Linux Mint 17 Qiana", using gcc 4.8.4.

What can I do to compile it successfully?

Comment: Can you update your question with information regarding your compiler and environment?

Comment: @WarrenSeine Thanks for your answer, I added the requested informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the issue with GCC 4.8.2, but not GCC 4.9.2.

You should upgrade your compiler to GCC 4.9.2. Since Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, you should be able to use this [Ubuntu Toolchain PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test).